# Scrape Dynamic Site not returning specific href beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, dynamic, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape this [site](https://www.reclameaqui.com.br/empresa/portal-da-prefeitura-de-sao-paulo/lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=1) with selenium and beautifulSoup. However I think I'm doing something wrong as I can't return the href from the specific class('card-content).

So I used this:

```
links = [link.get('href') for link in soup.select('a')]
```

Which bring several results that doesn't matter to me. I want all the href that starts with '/portal..' which would result in posterior work.

The code I came up to try to get what I want is the follow:

```
links = []
for i in range(1,510):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver')
    url = "https://www.reclameaqui.com.br/empresa/portal-da-prefeitura-de-sao-paulo/lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=%s" % i
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    href = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href]')]
    if len(href) in ('321','323','324','325','326'):
        for j in range(262,272):
            links.append(href[j])
    elif len(href) in ('330','331'):
        for j in range(264,274):
            links.append(href[j])
    else:
        for j in range(258,274):
            links.append(href[j])    
    driver.close()
    time.sleep(2)
```

The 'if-else' was to try to get the correct href from the list of href that it returned, but for some reason it only activate the else statement and I still have to apply some clean up afterwards.

There is a way to get only the href(href="/portal-da-prefeitura-de-sao-paulo/som-alto-de-propaganda-com-autos-falantes_Jg3fS46He5aLo9PZ/") I want from div class="card-content"?

Any ideas on what I have been doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this :

```
webPageSource = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(webPageSource, "html.parser")

links_ = soup.findAll('a',{'class':'link-complain-id-complains label-not-answered'})

for i in range(0,len(links_)):

     print(links_[i]['href'])
```

[image]

Comment: Using find_all() was a better option than replace indeed. Thanks